# Using AJAX/Django to Fill Customer Address

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have an 'Order' form where the user selects a Customer (from a foreignkey dropdown). There is a text field for Customer Address in the same form which I would like to auto-populate when the user selects Customer based on my Customer model which contains both customer name and customer address.  My understanding is that this would require some AJAX, but I am completely inexperienced with AJAX and I'm hoping someone could show me an example of how to do this as I will have many similar cases through my program.

MODELS.PY

```
class Customers(models.Model):

    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    c_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Orders(models.Model):
    reference = models.IntegerField()
    c_name = models.ForeignKey(Customers) #dropdown the user selects from
    ship_to = models.CharField(max_length=1000) #this is the field I want to populate automatically
...
```

FORMS.PY

```
class CreateOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ('reference', 'c_name', 'ship_to', 'vessel', 'booking_no', 'POL',
        'DOL', 'COO', 'POE', 'ETA', 'pickup_no', 'terms', 'sales_contact', 'trucking_co', 'loading_loc', 'inspector', 'total_cases', 'total_fob', 'freight_forwarder', 'commodity', 'is_airshipment', 'credit')
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def add_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateOrderForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            reference_id = form.cleaned_data.get('reference')
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest', kwargs={'reference_id': reference_id})
    else:
    form = CreateOrderForm()
    objectlist = Customers.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'objectlist': objectlist,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_order.html', context)
```

when customer is selected from dropdown, ship_to should populate with c_address for that customer from the customer model without a refresh. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should make an api and use it with javascript on your html pages.

Start learning js and jQuery for the client side and then use [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for build the api.

Basically on client side you should put an action on dropdown change, make a request to the api and use the reponse to populate the other info.

Comment: Fair enough! Is there a way I can trigger the page to refresh when the user makes a selection from the dropdown and use .get() to retrieve the address in the meantime? I’m not sure how I can trigger a refresh other than with a submit button or something of that nature